# the state is always undefined

Tags: angular, ngrx

The subscribe is never called, yet I increment and decrement.

```
this.store.select('counter').subscribe(counter => {
  this.counter = counter;            
  console.log("subscribe", this.counter);
});
```

You can see my code on stackblitz to debug :

https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ivy-hntnex?file=src/app/components/comp1/my-counter/my-counter.component.ts

I don't understand, it's very strange.

Answer (score 1):

Change this line in app.module.ts:

```
StoreModule.forRoot({ count: counterReducer }),
```

to:

```
StoreModule.forRoot({ counter: counterReducer }),
```

When you're subscribing, you're looking for the `counter` but you had it registered as `count` in your AppModule.

Comment: Also it is a recommanded way to make use of the async pipe a most as possible : so you better user ```this.counter$ = this.store.select("counter");```and ```counter$: Observable<number>;``` with an ```async``` pipe on in the html template